# How do I get access to full XML string from either brower debugger or if not possible write to file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a large xmlText string I would like to either copy and paste somehow into a editor like notepadd++ that would be the easiest if possible
When I try to look at the variable in different browsers I cannot see the whole string. It truncates.
If that is not possible is there a way to write it to a local file.
I just tried to do this a few different ways and they have all failed.
Sounds like you are not allowed to write to local files ??
thanks for any help

```
                var xmlText = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc);
```

Comment: Use `document.write(xmlText);` to write it to the browser as content, then you can copy/paste/beautify etc.

Comment: That document.write() does output text but it doesn't seem like it is the whole XML text and there are no XML tags at all. I want to be able to see the XML tags like I can when I see xmlDoc in the browser watch

Comment: You'll need to do a view source after the document.write.  If it's not the whole document then there's something wrong beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function convertXMLToString(node) {
    if (node.xml) {
        return node.xml;
    } else if (XMLSerializer) {
        var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
        return serializer.serializeToString(node);
    }
}
document.getElementById("#id").innerHTML = convertXMLToString(your_xml_there);
```

Note that it won't work on old browsers.